# problems creating a JAR file

Tags: java, jar

If I understand correctly, a JAR file is the best way to distribute my Java program to another user, right?  I read [this tutorial](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/85application/jar/jar.html), and it was my understanding that I am to navigate to the correct folder in the command prompt and type the appropriate text.  To create a JAR file of my Clock.java file (located on my Desktop), I first create a Clock.mf file consisting of the following text:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Clock
```

I then went to the command prompt, typed the following text, and got this response:

```
C:\Users\[name]\Desktop>jar cmf Clock.mf Clock.jar Clock.class Clock.java
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I downloaded the sample Hello.jar file from the link I provided, and it does absolutely nothing when I download and double-click it.  Why is that?

Comment: add jar to your classpath

Comment: `jar` is either not installed or you don't have it's location in your `PATH` environment variable. Also, you don't need to include the `Clock.java` source file. Only the `class` files are to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In windows find your JDK bin directory i believe the default is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk(version number)\bin" copy the path to the folder. Now right click on 'This pc' (My computer on older OS's) > Properties > Advanced System Settings (top right) > Environmental Variables > find Path. Go to the end of Path and add a semicolon and paste the directory there.

[You can follow this link to a tutorial](http://condor.depaul.edu/slytinen/instructions/setupj2sewin7.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this, and am still getting the same error though.

Comment: you could try and enter the path your tried earlier and add jar.exe on the end EX: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk(version number)\bin\jar.exe' followed by your comands. so the full command would be:                 

 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk(version number)\bin\jar.exe" cmf Clock.mf Clock.jar Clock.class Clock.java      

Make sure to put the path in quotations. This should only be a temporary fix. you restarted the console right?

Comment: I did restart (and still had the same problem).  Your "temporary fix" allowed me to successfully create the JAR, but when I double-click it, nothing happens.

Comment: Is it a GUI application or console? if console use 'java -jar Clock.jar'

Comment: Can i ask why you are not using an IDE?

Comment: It was just something I put in to reach 15 characters.  I replaced it with asterisks to avoid confusion, but it looks like you commented prior to that.

Comment: I do all my work in an IDE.  Are you telling me that I can create my JARs in my IDE?

Comment: Depends on the IDE. eclipse?

Comment: Nope, jGRASP.  Anyway, why is nothing happening when I double-click the .jar file?

Comment: i am sorry but i do not know why. I use eclipse and in eclipse there is an option to export a run-able jar. I'll look into it though.

Comment: Alright i downloaded Hello.jar from the tutorial and the only way it is opening is with 'java -jar Hello.jar'

Comment: Hmm... is there any way to create something like a .exe from a Java file - where I can send it to someone and they double-click it and run it (assuming they have Java installed)?

Comment: Maybe try jarsplice (http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) i think this is what you are looking for.